# Parse Complexo de JSON

Tags: java, android, json

Estou a tentar fazer parse de um JSON, usando o GSON, mas existe uma parte complexa, porque eu não sei o nome das keys, logo não sei que nome devo usar nas variáveis para que o GSON faça o parse.
Pesquisei e parece que tenho de usar Map<>, mas nem assim estou a conseguir.

Exemplo JSON:

```
{
  "type": "typeString",
  "format": "json",
  "version": "4.13.35",
  "data": {
    "data1": {
      "version": "4.13.1",
      "id": "data1",
      "key": "238",
      "name": "John"
    },
    "data2": {
      "version": "4.13.1",
      "id": "data2",
      "key": "115",
      "name": "Hello"
    },
    "data3": {
      "version": "4.13.1",
      "id": "date3",
      "key": "26",
      "name": "Zeus"
    },
    "data4": {
      "version": "4.13.1",
      "id": "data4",
      "key": "143",
      "name": "Venus"
    }
  }
}
```

Classe feita:

```
public class MasterGSON {

    @SuppressWarnings("type")
    private String type;

    @SuppressWarnings("format")
    private String format;

    @SuppressWarnings("version")
    private String version;

    @SuppressWarnings("data")
    private Map<String, DataGSON> listChampion;

    public Map<String, DataGSON> getListChampion() {
        return listChampion;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public String getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public class DataGSON {


        private String version;

        private String id;

        private String key;

        private String name;


        public String getVersion() {
            return version;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Kiotto, inclua o código que já fez, da forma que está a pergunta esta muito ampla. Como assim não sabe as chaves? Seriam os atributos do JSON não? Esses atributos que estão no JSON de exemplo podem mudar? Que eu saiba o GSON consegue preencher sua classe usando `Reflection` nos campos.

Comment: O código que fiz foi esse em cima, depois faço:

 Gson gsonaux = new GsonBuilder().create();
 MasterGSON aux = gsonaux.fromJson(json, MasterGSON.class);

As variveis type, format, version veêm com dados, o listChampion vem null...

Eu não conheço as keys data1, data2, data3... Essas keys podem mudar e podem ter N keys

Comment: Oi, Kiotto, quando o pessoal tiver dúvidas à respeito da sua pergunta, é melhor **[edit]** a pergunta para esclarecer as coisas. Fica confuso se vc põe esse tipo de coisa nos comentários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O GSON faz o parsing corretamente se o nome do campo for igual ao do JSON. Porque ele usa `Reflection` para deserializar o objeto aninhado.

O atributo `listChampion` fica `null` porque ele faz uma associação direta das chaves do JSON com seu objeto. Ele encontra a chave `data` e por reflection busca um atributo com nome `data` na sua classe `MasterGSON`. Depois ele verifica o tipo, e deserializa conforme o tipo. No caso do `Map`, não importa o nome das chaves, o que vai importar é a estrutura interna do objeto `DataGSON`.

Apenas modificando o nome do atributo de `listChampion` para `data`, mas mantendo o `Map<String, DataGSON>` ele deserializa corretamente.

A classe ficaria:

```
public class MasterGSON {

    @SuppressWarnings("type")
    private String type;

    @SuppressWarnings("format")
    private String format;

    @SuppressWarnings("version")
    private String version;

    @SuppressWarnings("data")
    private Map<String, DataGSON> data;

    public Map<String, DataGSON> getListChampion() {
        return data;
    }

    // Demais getters/setters
}
```

Para deserializar o JSON fiz dessa maneira:

```
GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
MasterGSON gs = gsonBuilder.create().fromJson(json, MasterGSON.class);
```

No seu `Map<String, DataGSON>`, onde cada elemento é um par chave/valor do seu objeto `data`. Contanto que o nome desse objeto não mude, não importa o nome das chaves dentro dele.

Comment: Funcionou :)
Fui só mudar o `listChampion` por `data`.
Eu tinha ideia que o  `@SuppressWarnings("data")` servia para meter o nome da key que estamos à espera que vem do JSON, mas que depois o nome da variável podia ser com outro nome, afinal parece que estava enganado.. Ou isto só acontece neste caso especifico para Map<>?

Comment: O `SupressWarnings` é uma anotação do compilador Java para não emitir avisos durante a compilação, não tem relação com a biblioteca GSON. Incorporei na minha resposta o porquê de não ter funcionado, mas o fato de usar `Map` flexibiliza em termos de nome de chave para os atributos, o que vem a calhar no seu caso.

Comment: Que burrice a minha, claro que o `SuppressWarnings` não funciona, é como disseste, não tem nada relacionado com o GSON. O que estava a referir era o `@SerializedName`, mas troquei os nomes e por causa disso nada disto funcionava. Burrice do meu lado :(
Sorry..
Obrigado pela respostas, agora tudo funciona bem :)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar o [JSON Schema](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/). Simplesmente você passa o JSON e ela retorna o POJO, daí vc consegue utilizar o GSON.

Fiz um teste com o seu arquivo JSON e foi retornado essas classes, depois de gerado é só fazer alguns ajustes.
    -----------------------------------com.example.Data.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Data {

@Expose
private Data1 data1;
@Expose
private Data2 data2;
@Expose
private Data3 data3;
@Expose
private Data4 data4;

public Data1 getData1() {
return data1;
}

public void setData1(Data1 data1) {
this.data1 = data1;
}

public Data2 getData2() {
return data2;
}

public void setData2(Data2 data2) {
this.data2 = data2;
}

public Data3 getData3() {
return data3;
}

public void setData3(Data3 data3) {
this.data3 = data3;
}

public Data4 getData4() {
return data4;
}

public void setData4(Data4 data4) {
this.data4 = data4;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Data1.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Data1 {

@Expose
private String version;
@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String key;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Data2.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Data2 {

@Expose
private String version;
@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String key;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Data3.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Data3 {

@Expose
private String version;
@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String key;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Data4.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Data4 {

@Expose
private String version;
@Expose
private String id;
@Expose
private String key;
@Expose
private String name;

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public String getId() {
return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
this.id = id;
}

public String getKey() {
return key;
}

public void setKey(String key) {
this.key = key;
}

public String getName() {
return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
this.name = name;
}

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java-----------------------------------

package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class Example {

@Expose
private String type;
@Expose
private String format;
@Expose
private String version;
@Expose
private Data data;

public String getType() {
return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
this.type = type;
}

public String getFormat() {
return format;
}

public void setFormat(String format) {
this.format = format;
}

public String getVersion() {
return version;
}

public void setVersion(String version) {
this.version = version;
}

public Data getData() {
return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
this.data = data;
}

}
```

Comment: O problema é que nao conheço o nome das keys data1, data2... Eu meti esses nomes como exemplos. E além de não conhecer esses nomes, pode existir N dessas keys.

Comment: @Kiotto, @Douglas. Não conheço a biblioteca GSON, mas não é possível recuperar o Objeto `data` e iterar sobre as chaves dele e "parsear" o objeto dessa chave?

Comment: Entendi, então não vai dar para utilizar o GSON, tem que fazer na mão mesmo, sempre que tu achar um nó principal vai ter que varrer o mesmo... vou ver se consigo achar um exemplo.

Comment: Por que não escreve um `JsonDeserializer` para esse objeto?

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que o esquema do JSON não é estático, você pode usar o "DOM" de JSON que o GSON oferece (classes do [`package com.google.gson`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/package-summary.html): JsonObject, JsonArray, JsonPrimitive, JsonNull, JsonElement) - em vez de tentar fazer a deserialização do JSON para o tipo, você lidaria diretamente com a estrutura do JSON. Algo similar ao código abaixo:

```
JsonObject root = new JsonParser().parse(JSON).getAsJsonObject();
JsonObject data = root.get("data").getAsJsonObject();
for (Entry<String, JsonElement> property : data.entrySet()) {
    String propName = property.getKey();
    JsonElement propValue = property.getValue();
    // Faça o que quiser com o valor...
}
```